# Find Duplicates using Conditional Formatting (countifs) over multiple sheets (28,29,30,31)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

We are leaving Google Docs Spreadsheet to Excel (for more accountability for changes and find duplicates).  The workbook is set with a tab for each day of the month for truck shipments.  We are having issues scheduling multiple days for the same delivery/pickup.  Using countifs, I was able to use customer's name and check for duplicates by PO# or Shipment #.  I am trying to use Macro recorder over the 30 sheets, but have no success.  I can find duplicates for a single sheet, but not over multiple sheets.

I used Conditional Formatting -> New Rule -> Use formula ...

```
=countifs($F$1:$F$200,F1,$G$1,$G:$G$200,G1)>1 (This is for Customer Name and Shipment #)
```

The Customer Name and PO# I used similar formula but different code, this allows quicker change on certain documents.

Example: We want to ensure that there is not a double booking. Shipment is originally scheduled on 12 April by company.  Shipping/Trucking company calls on same order, but schedules on 17 April.  These would be on separate sheets (TAB = Date).   If rep enters information on April 17, we would like the cell to change color and "ALERT" the rep that a duplicate has been entered.

I am not sure if VBA or Macro or Format Painter is the best route for so many sheets.

Comment: Would it be possible to have or have a sample of that workbook so we could follow what you wish to do?

Comment: Could you explain as well the `Shipment is originally scheduled on 12 April by company. Shipping/Trucking company calls on same order, but schedules on 17 April.` part? It's not very clear

Comment: Welcome to the world of Warehouses -  The company that made the product will schedule a date for pick up prior to having a Shipping/Trucking company selected.  Once a Shipping/Trucking company is hired.  They Trucking company will call to schedule a pickup.  This is to double check to see if the producer had scheduled a pickup.  Some producers do not schedule for the trucking companies.  One vendor does.  Since the trucking company can very per pickup for the same producer, there are no preventing duplication.

Comment: We store the product until the producer can find a buyer and the trucking company delivers the goods.  This was previously done on Google Docs Spreadsheets.

Comment: Ok, looking at what the transactions, I can see you have a complex Excel system in place or you want to set, so let's address your issues one by one.
Could you please update your Question and use the **Numbering** to list one by one your issues? Then let's deal with them one at a time

Answer (score 0):

Addressing one by one your question:

### Cell Color Change alert: Excel Conditional Formatting

> If rep enters information on April 17, we would like the **cell to change color and "ALERT"** the rep that a duplicate has been entered.

The Best solution is to use **Excel Conditional Formatting** based on the criteria you wish it to use to alert you.

I'll update the post as I understand the other aspects of the question as it has several things to address at the same time.